# MacBook Pro's Trackpad stops working when connecting an external keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad

I'm trying to set up a new [Ergodox EZ](https://ergodox-ez.com) keyboard. Whenever I plug in the keyboard's via USB port, the MacBook's built-in Trackpad ceases to function. It responds to absolutely no input at all. This makes it impossible to configure the keyboard properly (I have to go through a wizard so the computer can figure out the keyboard uses an ANSI layout).

If I disconnect the keyboard temporarily, I can press next, plug the keyboard back in, and then continue with the wizard, but at the final screen I need my mouse again. So I have to disconnect → click → reconnect, at which point the wizard reappears from the beginning claiming that the keyboard could not be identified.

This is preventing me from successfully configuring the keyboard. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Goto System Preferences app → Accessibility → Mouse & Trackpad and see if "Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present" is checked? If so, uncheck it.

Comment: @NimeshNeema that fixed the issue, thank you! If you wanna write that as a response, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that plugging in the keyboard is causing macOS to detect a cursor control device (mouse).

Go to System Preferences app → Accessibility → Mouse & Trackpad and check if **Ignore built-in trackpad when mouse or wireless trackpad is present** is checked?

[image]

If it is, simply uncheck and try again. You should now be able to use the built-in Trackpad normally while your keyboard is plugged in.